# SubQuery Join Failed

Tags: mysql, sql, teradata

I am trying to find out the missing record in the target. I need the employee whose record are missing.

Suppose I have input source as

```
1,Jack,type1,add1,reg3,..,..,..,
2,Jack,type2,add1,reg3,..,,.,..,
3,Jack,type3,add2,reg4,..,.,..,.,
4,Rock,,,,,,,,
```

and I have output as

```
1,Jack,type1,add1,reg3,..,..,..,
4,Rock,,,,,,,,
```

I have 1000 numbers of rows for other employees and in target i don't have any duplicate records.
I need the employee who are present in source and target having different occurance
means  for e.g in above sample data I have 3 entries of jack and 1 entry of Rock in source

and in target I have only on entry of Jack and one for Rock

I am running below query and required output is Jack,3

How can I get it. I am getting error in below query

```
select A.EMP_NUMBER,A.CNT1
from

(select EMP_NUMBER,count(EMP_NUMBER) as CNT1
 from EMPLOYEE_SOURCE
 group by EMP_NUMBER ) as A

INNER JOIN 

 (select B.EMP_NUMBER,B.CNT2
  from (select EMP_NUMBER,count(EMP_NUMBER) as CNT2  
        from EMPLOYEE_TARGET 
        group by EMP_NUMBER )as B )

 ON (A.EMP_NUMBER = B.EMP_NUMBER)

 where A.CNT1 != B.CNT2
```

Please help.

Comment: Please add a complete table definition (relevant columns only) of your example tables. And please why the desired output is `Jack, 3`? I don't get it by your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't get the employee that have different number of rows in the two table when grouped by their name (I suppose Emp_Number is the field that contain the name if that what the query in the question return)

```
SELECT s.Emp_Number, Count(s.Emp_Number)
FROM   EMPLOYEE_SOURCE s
       LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_TARGET t ON s.Emp_Number = t.Emp_Number
GROUP BY s.Emp_Number
HAVING Count(s.Emp_Number) != Count(t.Emp_Number)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be really helpful if you specified the exact error you get.

If this is you actual query there are two things: There's no alias name for the 2nd Derived Table (btw, you don't need it at all) and at least in Teradata `!=`is not valid, this is SQL and not C.

```
select A.EMP_NUMBER,A.CNT1
from  
 (
  select EMP_NUMBER,count(EMP_NUMBER) as CNT1
  from EMPLOYEE_SOURCE
  group by EMP_NUMBER
 ) as A    
INNER JOIN 
 (
   select EMP_NUMBER,count(EMP_NUMBER) as CNT2  
   from EMPLOYEE_TARGET 
   group by EMP_NUMBER
 ) as B
ON (A.EMP_NUMBER = B.EMP_NUMBER)
where A.CNT1 <> B.CNT2
```

If an employee is missing in the 2nd table you might have to use an Outer Join as Serpiton suggested and add an additional WHERE-condition:
    where A.CNT1 <> B.CNT2
       or b.CNT2 IS NULL